# What's different in the process environment when toggling ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow?

Tags: c#, windows, process.start

I have a C# program invoking another program using Process.Start and ProcessStartInfo:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "myOtherProgram.exe";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; // bad boy here
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The weird part is "myOtherProgram.exe" takes about 25s for CreateNoWindow=true, and only 2s for CreateNoWindow=false. Starting "myOtherProgram.exe" from command prompt is only 2s too. For what I can tell the hiccup is starting the particular exe. Starting "C:\Windows\System32\where.exe" instead from my program works without a hitch.

**Q:** So, what the differences between having CreateNoWindow true or false *as seen by the started process*?

---

"myOtherProgram.exe" is a corporate internal (confidental, IP) abandonware based on unfamiliar third party components. The development environment is busted. I'm debugging it the best I can, but hoping any answer to the more general question can point me in the right direction. Cannot provide much more debugging details at this time.

---

I've located [the culprit](https://documentation.help/NI-Vision-LabWindows.CVI-Function/imaqSetWindowThreadPolicy.htm) in "myOtherProgram":

```
imaqSetWindowThreadPolicy(IMAQ_SEPARATE_THREAD);
```

> Determines the thread in which NI Vision creates windows. By default, NI Vision uses IMAQ_CALLING_THREAD. This policy creates windows in the thread that makes the first display function call for a given window number. If that thread does not process messages, set the window thread policy to IMAQ_SEPARATE_THREAD. Using this policy, NI Vision creates windows in a separate thread and processes messages for the windows automatically.

<strike>I'll open a ticket with NI and see what they have to say for themselves.</strike> Why of course our service agreement expired long ago because deserving good things is not my game. Dead end.

Comment: Does it matter if you do an extra indirection, for example by starting cmd.exe with the /c argument to start myOtherProgram.exe?

Comment: @rene Great idea, I'll try that and get back with results.

Comment: The description you quoted actually explains the problem. It's a problem with NI Vision not Process. The GUIs in all OSs work by sending messages to applications to tell them what to draw, what events happened (eg clicks) etc. Applications run a message pump (infinite loop) that receives those messages and processes them. A console application doesn't do that because it just doesn't have any windows to display or update. It just reads/writes to the standard input/output. The Console window is actually a terminal attached to the standard I/O

Comment: If the process you started *requires* Windows messages, starting it without a window will cause trouble. 30+ years ago applications that weren't built with multithreading in mind depended on Windows TIMER or IDLE messages for background processing. The application may be getting stuck until something times out if there's no visible window to receive messages.